# Zend framework 1 - Can't get through login page

Tags: php, session, redirect, zend-framework

I am trying to resolve a bug on a client's application, but i can't log in.

So i go to application.dev/metier/login, with application.dev as my virtual host, metier my admin route page and login the page to log in the application.

I complete the form, click on connect, i am getting logged in, redirected to the index page (application.dev/metier/index) but immediately after the redirection i am kicked out to the login page. The url is still application.dev/metier/index, but the i am seeing the login page as i was not authenticated.

I checked session, cleared after redirection. 
It is like it's working fine, I am known from database, inserted in session, known as admin, but kicked out no matter what i do. No error, no log. Zend do not enter indexAction().

I can't go to another page due to the routing, and if i try to put my informations in session before access login page, i have an error "too many redirections" (i am in authenticated so go to index, but no i am kicked out, but i am authenticated, but i am kicked out...).

I am on Zend framework 1.12.18, Windows 10, with laragon (Kaspersky as antivirus). I also tried with wamp, and on an Ubuntu VM with xampp, same problem. I tried on another computer, same problem.
It works on the developer who gave me the source code. He gave me the original code and the code with his modification (of application.ini mainly), both give me the "error".

Controller:

```
 public function loginAction() {
            try {
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

        if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
            $this->redirect('/metier/index/');
            return;
        }else{
            Zend_Session::regenerateId();
        }
        $loginForm = new Application_Form_Admin_Login();
        $request = $this->getRequest();

        if ($request->isPost()) {
            if ($loginForm->isValid($request->getPost())) {
                if ($this->_process($loginForm->getValues())) {
                    // We're authenticated! Redirect to the home page
                    $this->_helper->redirector('index', 'index');
                }
            } else {
                Log::debug('User sent invalid data.', __FILE__, __LINE__);
                Log::debug($request->getPost(), __FILE__, __LINE__);
                Log::debug('Errors: ', __FILE__, __LINE__);
                Log::debug($loginForm->getErrors(), __FILE__, __LINE__);
                $this->view->error = Zend_Registry::get('Language')->errors->login->error;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //$this->view->error = 'Wrong username and/or password';
        $this->redirect('/metier/login/');
        return;
    }
    $this->view->form = $loginForm;
}


    protected function _process($values) {

    if (!trim($values['username']) || !trim($values['password'])) {
        $this->view->error = Zend_Registry::get('Language')->errors->login->empty;
        return false;
    }

    // Get our authentication adapter and check credentials
    $adapter = $this->_getAuthAdapter();
    $adapter->setIdentity($values['username']);
    $adapter->setCredential($values['password']);
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);
    Log::debug('Authentication returned result code: ' . $result->getCode(), __FILE__, __LINE__);


    switch ($result->getCode()) {
        case Zend_Auth_Result::SUCCESS:
            $mdlMetierDep = new Application_Model_DbTable_MetierDepartement();

            $user = $adapter->getResultRowObject();

            $metDepObj = $mdlMetierDep->fetchRow(array('id_metier = ?' => $user->id_metier, 'id_departement = ?' => $user->id_departement));
            if (!$metDepObj) {
                $this->view->error = Zend_Registry::get('Language')->errors->login->error;
                return $this->_redirect('/metier/login/');
            }
            $user->Role = Acl::ROLE_ADMIN_METIER;
            $user->id_metier_departement = $metDepObj->getIdMetierDepartement();
            $user->metier = $metDepObj->findMetier()->toArray();
            $user->department = $metDepObj->findDepartement()->toArray();
            // to help thwart session fixation/hijacking
            // store user object in the session
            $authStorage = $auth->getStorage();
            $authStorage->write($user);
            $this->_redirect('/metier/index/');
            break;

        case Zend_Auth_Result::FAILURE_IDENTITY_NOT_FOUND:
        case Zend_Auth_Result::FAILURE_CREDENTIAL_INVALID:
        default:

            $this->view->error = Zend_Registry::get('Language')->errors->login->error;
            break;
    }



    if ($result->isValid()) {
        $user = $adapter->getResultRowObject();
        //$auth->getStorage()->write($user);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

The login and reporting actions (just for informations, zend do not goes in it)

```
public function indexAction() {
    $this->go('reporting');
}
public function reportingAction() {
    $this->loadJs(('/scripts/metier/general.js'));
    $this->loadCss(('/styles/metier/DataTable.css'));
    $this->loadJs(('/scripts/jquery.dataTables.js'));
    $this->loadJs(('/scripts/metier/data-table.js'));
}
```

Init function :

```
    public function init() {
    /* Initialize action controller here */
    parent::init();
    $this->loadCss(('/styles/web/tables2.css'));
    $this->loadJs(('/scripts/web/tinyMceConfigs.js'));
    $this->language = Zend_Registry::get('Language');
    $this->view->language = $this->language;


    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

    if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
        $this->storage = $auth->getStorage()->read();
        $this->_getLogo();
    } else {
        $this->view->noLogo = true;
    }

    //enum field for indicateurs
    $this->view->frequence = array('M', 'T', 'S', 'A');
    $this->view->sens = array(
        'A' => 'Croissant',
        'D' => 'DÃ©croissant',
    );
    $this->view->formulaType = array(
        0 => 'rule',
        1 => 'min',
        2 => 'max',
        3 => 'avg');

    $this->view->FormulaOperand = array(
        0 => '+',
        1 => '-',
        2 => '/',
        3 => '*');

    $this->view->tableauTypes = array(Constants::TABLEAU_STRUCTURE_DETAILLE, Constants::TABLEAU_STRUCTURE_COMPTEURS, Constants::TABLEAU_STRUCTURE_GRAPH);
    $this->view->operands = array('+', '-', '*', '/');

    $this->view->pageTypes = array(
        Constants::PAGE_GARDE,
        Constants::PAGE_CONTENU,
        Constants::PAGE_TABLEAUX,
    );
    $this->view->HautEtBasTypes = array(
        Constants::HEADER => Constants::HEADER,
        Constants::FOOTER => Constants::FOOTER,
    );
    $this->loadCss('styles/forms.css', 'form_css');

    $this->view->config = Zend_Registry::get('AppConfig');

    $ajaxContext = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');
    $ajaxContext->addActionContext('add-metier', 'json')
            ->setAutoJsonSerialization(true)
            ->initContext();


    $this->_loggedInUser = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity();


    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
}
```

Classname :

```
class MetierController extends Reporting_Controller {...}
```

After debugging, it goes to $this->_redirect('/metier/index') and then kick me out

What could be the problem ?

Comment: We need some code to help you out. Show us the php methods of the login action and the index action (or better the whole controller).

Comment: Code added to the question :)

Comment: Are you shure you are going to 'metier/index' and not to 'index/index'. Because this is the redirect in the loginAction(). Does the 'index/index' action redirect you to 'metier/index'?

Comment: Yes. It goes to the _process function, in the switch with Zend_Auth_Result::SUCCESS, it stores $user in the $_SESSION, it redirect me to /metier/index (i can see it in the url and in the debugger) but does not go to indexAction(). I am still stuck on login page

Comment: But in that case there will be a second redirect after you return from the _process function. I guess it will overwrite the first one. It's the line after the comment "// We're authenticated! Redirect to the home page".

Comment: _process function doesn't return anything because it redirect the page. Trusting the debugger, the code stops after the redirection in _process function. It does not go further. I commented the line you're talking about, just in case, it changes nothing.

Comment: Then please add the code of the indexAction.

Comment: It does not enter indexAction(), that's the problem.

Comment: If you get a redirect, than it's not the login action. It must go somewhere. Without having any more code or being able to see the behaviour, it's impossible to tell what's going on.

Comment: Added indexAction(). When i debug, the redirection from _process function launch the loginAction()

Comment: Can you post the complete controller? Including the class name? And is there an init() method?

Comment: I just can't post 7k code lines. I added the init method and the class name